# Problema na transformação de URL para título da pergunta

Tags: bug

Ao colar a URL do SO o sistema transforma automaticamente em um link já com o título correto da pergunta. Percebi agora que o sistema não está removendo por completo a URL quando existe algum caracter acentuado.

Exemplo:

```
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9296/buscar-os-dados-dos-últimos-7-dias-a-partir-da-data-actual/
```

Fica assim:
[Buscar os dados dos últimos 7 dias a partir da data actual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9296/buscar-os-dados-dos-%C3%BAltimos-7-dias-a-partir-da-data-actual/)

A URL só é cortada até antes do `ú`.

**UPDATE:**

Outro problema parecido. A URL abaixo é transformada em link corretamente no *preview*, mas no post final ela é cortada antes do `$http`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Firefox, Chrome e IE não codificam esta na hora de copiar.

Answer (score 2):

Será que o browser embeleza as URLs na hora de mostrar? Por exemplo, no Chrome, se eu copio a URL desta pergunta e colo aqui, eu vejo uma versão encodada dela:

```
http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2437/problema-na-transforma%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-url-para-t%c3%adtulo-da-pergunta
```

Mas olhando para a minha barra de endereços, os acentos já estão desencodados:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Verdade. Testei aqui e vi que no Firefox o funcionamento é o mesmo. Eu vi esse erro em uma pergunta em que o autor provavelmente copiou e colou diretamente da barra de endereços do IE (que não codifica a URL).